# Android application error on starting new activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm having a problem in my Android 1.6 app. I have a two java class files, each with their corresponding XML layout file.

When I perform the following:

```
Intent ii = new Intent(this,
           PatientEntry.class);
startActivity(ii);
```

I get an application error:

> Sorry! The application XXXX has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

I have added the following to my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name=".PatientEntry"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

Why am I getting these errors and how do I fix it?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add PatientEntry activity to your manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".PatientEntry"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be there are problems in PatientEntry class. If you give the logcat with the error specified then guess we can help.